# .NetCore, Version=v5.0 is not installed Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 for developint UWP apps. However I tried to install Visual Studio 2017 a few days ago. It worked, but I can't use Visual Studio 2017 to develop Windows 8 apps, so I deleted it.

Now my Visual Studio 2015 says for UWP projects:

> One or more projects require a framework SDK (.NetCore,Version=v5.0)
>   that is either not installed or is inclded of a future update to
>   Visual Studio.

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (Version 14.0.25431.01) that I have.

I have tried to download this update:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=14.0&sbp=TargetPackMissing&plcid=0x409&o1=.NETCore,Version=v5.0

But not work. I tried to uninstall my SDKs, not work. I reinsalled Visual Studio, not works...

Any idea, how can I repair this?

Comment: What operating system are you running?  I hope you are not trying to open a project you created in VS2017 in VS2015?  Unless you change the target NET Framework you will continue to get that error.  "But not work" does not provide any clarification.  Be specific, provide logs, "it doesn't work" does not tell us anythign that allows us to submit an answer to your question.

Comment: For me neither... I made this solution in Visual Studio 2015, I use Windows 10, I can't even open a project that I create now in VS 2015 for UWP... I don't have any logs, it just throws a popup and show me this error message..

Comment: You have the [Windows 10 SDK 1607](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) installed?

Comment: What is odd is the fact .NET Framework 5.0 is installed with Visual Studio 2017, the fact a new solution requires .NET Framework 5.0 instead of .NET 4.6.2 is part of your problem, your error indicates a Visual Studio installation problem.  .NET Core 1.0 was installed with Update 3.  I will ask again, we need more information other then, "it doesn't work"

Comment: Well, I tried to uninstall VS 2015, Tried to repair too... but it did not worked... Do you have any idea how to repair VS2015... I dont want to reinstall windows :D

Comment: You repair Visual Studio like any other program.  You run the installer again.  I suggest you download the VS2015 Update 3 ISO, remove VS2015, then install VS2015 Update 3 and be sure you include ALL require features.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2017 again and now I can load UWP projects in Visual Studio 2015 :D ...